# Jersey RestAPI Json conversion

Tags: jaxb, jersey

I have built a Jersey Rest API producing the JSON response.
Response looks like below:

```
{
  "errorOccured": "false",
  "transaction": [
    {
      "businessDate": "10/25/2011",
      "canViewReceipt": "false",
      "modifiedBusinessDate": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Jersey Resource response generation is done like below.

```
Response.ok(myObject).build();
```

The problem here is "errorOccured" field has been marked boolean in the backing XSD but during conversion its getting generated as String.

This breaks the consuming JavaScript which checks for errors:

```
if(json.errorOccured) {
          //do something
}
```

Any idea how this can be generated as booleans:

```
{
  "errorOccured": false,
  "transaction": [
    {
      "businessDate": "10/25/2011",
      "canViewReceipt": false,
      "modifiedBusinessDate": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add your myObject class

Comment: the only way is set errorOccured as boolean in your class, if you are using a map do this map.put("errorOcurred", false);

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by 'backing XSD'? You're talking about JSON formatting, what role does the XSD play?